# Storing a value when using Combine

Tags: swift, reactive, combine

I'm learning Combine in Swift. I'm trying to load some data from an URL. Let's call it `Key`.

```
class Key: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

The data has to be stored in this `KeyContainer` in this example. It's a third party tool in my actual app. I'm just using a simplified version for this example.

```
class KeyContainer {
    var keys = [Key]()
    func store(key: Key) -> Self {
        keys.append(key)
        return self
    }
}
```

I have created a `KeyLoader` which has a function `fetchOrUseExisting`. The goal is either downloaded a key or use the previously downloaded key from a specific URL. I want to store the URL that I used to download the key and on subsequent calls, use the previously downloaded key.

My issue is with how I'm storing that key in the chain of calls. `self.completedUrls.insert(url)`.

1. It references self which I think creates a retain cycle
2. It doesn't seem, for lack of a better word, "reactive" in this chain of transformations.

Is there a more "reactive" way to store the URL that was used so that I don't download it again?

```
class KeyLoader {
    var completedUrls = Set<URL>()
    private let _container = KeyContainer()
    
    func fetchOrUseExisting(from url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<KeyContainer, Error> {
        //Using a local var so that I don't retain a reference to self in the publisher
        let theContainer = _container
        //If we previously fetched the key, don't do it again
        guard !completedUrls.contains(url) else {
            return Just(_container).tryMap({ $0 }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        //We didn't fetch it, fetch it now
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: url))
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: Key.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .map({ theContainer.store(key: $0) })
            .map({
                //Store URL used to download key
                // :( Referencing self and performing a side effect unrelated to the transform
                self.completedUrls.insert(url)
                return $0
            })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid retain cycles, use `[weak self]` in closures. `.handleEvents` operator can also be used for side effects. And `setFailureType(to:)` can be used to instead of a `tryMap` to amend the failure type of `Just`. Other than those points, what doesn't work here? If the question is "how to make it better", then SO isn't a good place for that, given that it's opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks @NewDev, do you want to turn this into an answer?